# UserInfo SalesForce

Tags: salesforce

var SalesforceOAuthPlugin = {

```
/**
* Obtain authentication credentials, calling 'authenticate' only if necessary.
* Most index.html authors can simply use this method to obtain auth credentials
* after onDeviceReady.
*   success - The success callback function to use.
*   fail    - The failure/error callback function to use.
* PhoneGap returns a dictionary with:
*   accessToken
*   refreshToken
*   clientId
*   userId
*   orgId
*   loginUrl
*   instanceUrl
*   userAgent
*/
getAuthCredentials: function(success, fail) {
    PhoneGap.exec(success, fail, "com.salesforce.oauth","getAuthCredentials",[]);
},
```

SalesforceOAuthPlugin.getAuthCredentials(getUserid(), getAuthCredentialsError);

I am trying to get the id of the user using the above function, but its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use link of this format `https://na1.salesforce.com/id/1/1`
na1 - salesforce instance, first 1 - organizationId, next 1 - userId.

Note, that in such get you should be logged (provide OAuth token).

I think that actual userId you provide in URL, or have mapping between token and id.